# PHP code not working on ipage hosting?

Tags: hosting, server

My code is working well on localhost and also on godaddy server.But on ipage I am getting "500 Internal Server error" with this code.
My local server has PHP Version 5.4.7  and my ipage hosting has PHP Version 5.3.13

```
         public function cms($cid,$vars) {
   global $db; 
    //fetch cms data from database 

          $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cms");
          $stmt->execute();
          $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        

       return $row;

   if ($cid == ""){
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cms");
            $stmt->execute();
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

           return $row;
      }

      else {
          $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cms WHERE id=? ");
          $stmt->execute(array($cid));
          $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    



        if ($vars == "") {
    return $row;
        }
        else {
            $ret = [];
            foreach ($vars as $var) {
                $ret[] = [
                    $var => $row[0][$var]
                        ];
                }
            return $ret;
         }

        }  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its version problem and for that you need to ask your hosting provider(ipage) to make your php version same as your local version..

Also check out your .htaccess file too, cos. some time redirection can also give this types of error.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone facing internal server (500) error in ipage, you can chat or call them, then they will upgrade your version to 7 or above.
you can check your php version using this code.

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```